# Solution to equations

Tags: inequality, polynomials, systems-of-equations, integers, symmetric-polynomials

Find all possible integers $(a,b,c,d)$ such that $$\sum_{\sigma}\frac{1}{a}=\frac{2018}{abcd}$$ $$abcd+\sum_{\sigma} ab -\sum_{\sigma} a +3=0$$.

It factorises into $\prod_{a,b,c,d} (1-a)=-2018$ and then there are a lot of cases which I can't handle.

Comment: I would like to see it written out, I suppose, to be sure.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Here you go: $abc+acd+abd+bcd=2018$ and $ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd-a-b-c-d=2015-abcd$

Comment: About your new problem. $2018=2\cdot1009$, where $1009$ is a prime number.

Answer (score 1):

The first condition gives $$\sum_{cyc}abc=2018.$$

Thus,
$$1-\sum_{cyc}a+\frac{1}{4}\sum_{sym}ab-\sum_{cyc}abc+abcd=1+2015-2018$$ or
$$(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)(1-d)=-2$$ and we got not so many very strange cases.

How we can get $\sum\limits_{cyc}abc=2018?$

For your new problem use that $1009$ is a prime number.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry. There was an error in the post.

Comment: I think now you can solve this problem. By the way, the previous problem is solved. I think it's better to restore the starting problem and to open a new topic. Do it please.

Comment: Yes I believe so. Some case chasing.

Comment: $1009$ is a prime number, which gives not so many cases.